# Proof of series expansion of $\operatorname{arctanh}(e^{is})$ for $s\in(0,\pi)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, trigonometry, power-series, trigonometric-series

I would to know how to prove that the series expansion of $\operatorname{arctanh}(e^{is})$ for $s\in(0,\pi)$ is:

$$\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{e^{is(2m-1)}}{2m-1}.$$

We know by Taylor series that
$$\operatorname{arctanh}(z)=\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{z^{2m-1}}{2m-1},$$
for $|z|<1$. The case $z=1$ is clear, but I don't know how to see the case $z=e^{is}.$

Thanks for all.

Comment: Hint:- $|e^{is}|=1$ for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$. Because $e^{is}$ forms a unit circle around the origin.

Comment: @RAHUL The problem is that $e^{is}$ is on the boundary of the circle of convergence of the series. For example, it dos not converge when $s=0$. The challange is to show that it still converges however when $0<s<\pi$.

Comment: As you are aware, the Maclaurin series of the inverse hyperbolic tangent is
$$\operatorname{arctanh}(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^{2k-1}}{2k-1}\\ \text{for }|z|<1$$
We'd like to investigate the boundary convergence. Let $z=e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$. 
We want to see for which $\theta$ the sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\underbrace{\frac{e^{i(2k-1)\theta}}{2k-1}}_{:=a_k(\theta)}$$ 
Converges. To do this, use the *ratio test*. Have a look at the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}(\theta)}{a_n(\theta)}\right|$$

Comment: Use summation by parts to show that the partial  sums of numerators (geometric series with  $z^2$ as the basic term) are always bounded unless $z=\pm 1$ and this immediately implies the (conditional) convergence of the series on the unit circle everywhere but at $\pm 1$, so in particular for all $s$ in the post

Comment: @K.defaoite Isn't the ratio test inconclusive as $|e^{i(2n-1)\theta}|=|e^{i(2n+1)\theta}|=1$? The Dirichlet test should be applied in this case.

Comment: Yeah! But I want to know not only that the series converges, but why we have the equality.

Comment: @Ivan You can use Abel's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem